# Laravel Nova custom field, prevent submit form on press 'Enter' key

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I created a custom Nova `Field` to autocomplete addresses via Google Place API.

When I select the suggested address from autocomplete dropdown and press 'Enter' key, the resource `Create` form is getting submitted.

Is there any way to prevent keypress event going up after `address` input field received the event in Vue.js component or from Nova side, to prevent the form from getting submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution

Just have to put `@keypress.enter.prevent` in `input` tag

```
            <input
                    :id="field.name"
                    type="text"
                    class="w-full form-control form-input form-input-bordered"
                    :class="errorClasses"
                    :placeholder="field.name"
                    v-model="value"
                    @keypress.enter.prevent
            />
```